# very basic c question

Tags: c++, c

as we use pointers in the argument list of functions like

```
void f(int *);
```

this means that this function will receive a pointer to an integer 
but what does this means

```
void f(int ***);
```

and

```
void f(int **=0)
```

Comment: Retagged the question as `C`, there is nothing C++ish here though of course one can do C within a C++ file.

Comment: what? default parameter values aren't C, but probably won't affect the solution at all...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
void f(int ***);
```

means that the function receives a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to an int. This would work with it:

```
int x=42;
int *px=&x;
int **ppx=&px;
int ***pppx=&ppx;
f(pppx);
```

Now about the 2nd one, its a function that receives a pointer to a pointer to an int, and if you give it nothing, it defaults to 0.

```
int x=42;
int *px=&x;
int **ppx=&px;
f(ppx);  // pt to pt to x
f();     // same as f(0)
```

---

UPDATE:

A practical application of this kind of double pointers is a memory allocation routine like:

```
bool alloc(T **mem, int count);
```

This function returns `true`/`false` depending on whether or not it worked and would update the pointer you pass in with the real memory address, like this:

```
T *mem;
verify(alloc(&mem, 100));
```

You pass in an uninitialized pointer and the function can overwrite it with a real value because you passed a pointer to the actual pointer. At the end, `mem` contains a pointer to valid memory.

Another application, more common but a lot less enlightening, is an array of arrays (so-called jagged arrays).

Comment: yes i understood, but is this not very confusing stuff that we are passing pointer to pointer to pointer to pointer to a function. is it mostly used in programming or not?

Answer (score 5):

```
int ***
```

is *a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to an int*. Think of it as `(((int*)*)*)`.

```
void f(int **=0)
```

This function takes a pointer to an int pointer as an argument, but can also be called without arguments in which case the argument will be 0.

Answer (score 4):

```
void f(int ***);
```

Here `f` takes a pointer to pointer to pointer to an `int`.

```
void f(int **=0)
```

This function takes a pointer to pointer to an `int` as an argument, but this arguments is optional and has a default value of 0 (i.e null)

Answer (score 1):

```
void f(int ***);
```

here the function argument is a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to an int (or more likely to many of them).

```
void f(int **=0)
```

and here it's just a pointer to a pointer to an int that gets initialized to be 0 (the pointer to the ... is 0, not the int) if the argument is not specified when the function is invoked (optional parameter).

Comment: What C standard is this?  I get a syntax error when I compile straight or with -std=c99.

Comment: The first line should work with any C compiler but the 2nd is actually not C but C++ and thus works only with a C++ compiler.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking about is [Multiple Indirection](http://boredzo.org/pointers/#multiple_indirection).  That page sums up the problem very well, I highly recommend reading that entire page on pointers, it is golden.

Answer (score -3):

```
void f(int ***);
```

As the other answers explain, this is a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to an int. It suggest to me that the programmer was not a very good programmer - he (and it was almost certainly a he) was too busy showing off how clever he was with 3 levels of indirection to consider the difficulty of maintaining overly obscure code like this. I've never had to use 3 levels of indirection in approx 20 years of programming in C and C++, and rarely use 2.

Comment: ya i saw this syntax in a question , this becomes very very confusing when we pass arguments to the functions like pointer to pointer to pointer to pointer to integer to the function

Comment: what you say about the usage of such a syntax in c++ programming?

Comment: Sexist, unimaginative and condescending. Would give more than -1 if i could.

Comment: He's looking for an answer to an academic-type question, not for a code review.

Comment: I could make an extremely condescending (as condescending as yours) but factual statement about C programmers who have rarely used 2 levels of indirection in 20 years of programming, and about those who think that there is a specific person (and with a specific gender yet) who is the source of the code in an abstract question like "what does ... mean".